# Why does adding a frame() to an image add padding in between the image and it's sibling?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-layout

Why does adding a frame() to an image add padding in between the image and it's sibling? E.g. why is there padding underneath the A, but not the B, in this example? Thank you!

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A")
                .border(Color.red, width:1)
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .frame(minHeight:50)
                .border(Color.black, width:1)
        }
        .border(Color.green, width:1)
        VStack {
            Text("B")
                .border(Color.red, width:1)
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .border(Color.black, width:1)
        }
        .border(Color.green, width:1)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because symbol images are treated like *text* by SwiftUI. Each symbol is a "glyph".

Layout out

```
VStack {
    Text("A")
    Image(systemName: "globe")
}
```

is a bit like laying out two lines of text (though not *literally* two *lines*, because `lineSpacing` doesn't have an effect on this). Because these are all text, the `VStack` tries to make it look like one whole "text block", and doesn't add extra space between them. That is how *text* is supposed to flow.

Once you add a `frame`, the `VStack` doesn't see them as the same *text* block anymore, and adds the default spacing it normally adds between views. You can see this in effect when you add non-symbol images, or other non-text views:

```
// this also adds default spacing
VStack {
    Text("A")
    Rectangle().fill(.red)
}
```

```
// this too!
VStack {
    Text("A")
    Image("some non-symbol image")
}
```

You can remove the default spacing by setting `spacing: 0`.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer. May I ask if you know where there is documentation that explains this behavior? I don't think it's included in the VStack, Text or Image documentation.

Comment: @JohnCashew the initialiser [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/init(alignment:spacing:content:)) says “or nil if you want the stack to choose a default distance for each pair of subviews” for the `spacing` parameter. There is also [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-the-default-spacing-in-swiftui-stacks-non-zero/64006).